# Sort by title asc on Solr not working as expected

Tags: solr, content-search

When trying `sort` search results in Solr using `title (alphabetical) asc or desc` does not work as expected and not sorted.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`title_t` is a `text_general` field in Solr. Which is **tokenized** field so sorting will not work. If you want sorting then the field needs to be of string type (with _s suffix)

You can try a few things-

1. Create a `computed index` field that is of string type and apply sort on that.
2. Convert the title field from `text` to `string` via Sitecore patch config and apply sort
3. Create a `copyField` in Solr from text to string and then apply sort order on the string field.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Surya and just putting brief details to provide more context to achieve it.

**Solution 1**

When you want to sort on a specific field, always make sure the field isn’t `tokenized` within Solr, and that the casing of the values is always the same, **Test** would be sorted differently then **test**.

This means that when you want to sort on Title, you should add an extra field that isn’t tokenized, and that is lowercase. You can create a Computed Field. so that the Solr schema does not have to be edited manually.

First of all, we create a Computed Field class, which uses the ReferenceField as a reference to the field from where it should take the value from.

```
namespace Example
{
    public class SortReferenceComputedField : IComputedIndexField
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceField { get; set; }
        public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
        {
            var indexItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;
            var field = indexItem?.Item?.Fields[ReferenceField];
            if (field != null && field.HasValue)
            {
                return field.Value.ToLower();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

After that, all we have to do is register the Computed Field by adding a configuration file. Please note that you can use the same SortReferenceComputedField type for each field that you want to be able to sort on.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" search:require="solr">
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="sorttitle" referenceField="title" storageType="no" indexType="untokenized">Example.SortReferenceComputedField, Example</field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

As you can see in the example above, we create a new field called **sorttitle** that uses the value from the **title** field. For the last step, just go to the Title Asc and Title Desc sortings, and make sure that the facet that is used there, points to the newly created **sorttitle** field.

**Solution 2** **(Not recommended)**

Another way is directly update the managed-schema within Solr.

It is possible with Solr, to create a new field type with the `LowerCaseFilterFactory` and the `TrimFilterFactory` as indexing analyzers, and then use a `copyField` definition to create the field.

**Note:** This is not a recommended way as you have to (manually) edit the managed-schema within Solr and changes will be overwritten when the next time managed-schema is populated from Sitecore, cumbersome to maintain the manual schema changes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks it works for me , but there's odd behavior when page load first time search result displays only 3 items while i configured page size parameter to be 8 , do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it works for you, If this answer or any solved your issue or helps to resolve it, please mark it as accepted for the community. For more details https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers